# Flyway migration scripts between different git branches

Tags: flyway

We have multiple git branches lets say A and B which have same sql scripts for now.
Now we have to start creating new scripts on branch B where after a while eventually that will be merged to main branch. Now if my branch B is exceeded 
example:

- Branch A has v1, v2 scripts and
- Branch B has v1,v2,v3,v4.

In case i want to use v4 migration script file in branch A with the same name how do i do that ?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/38925217/299023